# Why was my answer deleted?

Tags: discussion, moderators, answers

Why was my answer to this question deleted?
[Which scripts have been used to write Sanskrit?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/10039/which-scripts-have-been-used-to-write-sanskrit)

My answer does not violate any of the criteria listed in the help center as [candidates for deletion](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/help/deleted-answers).
Also, I was not even notified that it was deleted. Is this courtesy no longer available at Hinduism.SE ?

Comment: Its not deleted but converted into comment, its on 2nd number in question comments.

Comment: I think its SE policy to not have deletion notification.

Comment: And deletion reason looks like "partial answer" and it seems to have got one downvote too, maybe mod converted it into comment because he seems it retainable as comment  but not as answer.

Comment: can moderator do that, without the user's consent? REMOVE answer and have it as COMMENT just Because MODERATOR(and not the community) thinks so?

Comment: @AADTechnical It's and SE feature and it is used in other SE site's too.  What you suppose to do with one liner incomplete answers? Leaving comment hardly help and new user mostly don't have comment privilege, So this power comes handy in there.

Comment: @AADTechnical Anyways SE believes are are more in community building rather then asking for user's consent. Didn't we edit user question and answer without user's consent?  But i do thing there should be a notification for it which SE lacks for deletion.

Comment: We don't delete answer if we want to, multiple users raise flags and it looked more like a comment rather than an answer and hence it was converted into a comment and it was not just completely deleted. In the initial stage of the site, we used to comment on every answer to provide additional details... since the site is getting bigger in size, we find it difficult to keep a track of such short answers which are better as comments and hence we take necessary action instead of keeping the answer as is. I hope this explains.

Comment: If you still think it's an issue, I'll undelete it because I think most of the users now know better than moderators do.

Comment: @AADTechnical It's not because JUST MODERATOR wanted to delete the answer but SOME OTHER USERS FLAGGED the answer as it *not an answer* and since the answer doesn't provide any detailed explanation it is better suited as a comment.

Comment: @moonstar2001 flag your answer and just write to undelete it and I will do that. Don't want to discuss anymore over this :)

Comment: @Mr.Alien Why is it not an answer? The answer is actually quite on point, if I may say so myself.As I pointed out, it does not violate any criterion listed in the helpcenter.Long-windedness does not a good answer make.I think you should restore the answer because useful information may be lost otherwise.Regardless, mods may do what they will based on how they interpret rules. Users will modify their participation accordingly. I personally took a break for some time but returned when I saw some questions that needed guidance which was not forthcoming.

Comment: @moonstar2001 http://meta.hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/456/why-was-my-answer-deleted?noredirect=1#comment1403_456 .. Also, again, your answer was not deleted, it is simply converted to a comment.

Comment: @Mr.Alien I am not campaigning for un-deleting my answer. You need not  restore it just because I asked you just as you did not have to delete it just because someone else asked for it. A judicious weighing of the merits of the answer is called for. I am done discussing as well. Thanks.

Comment: @Mr.Alien What about subsequent comments to the answer? Those have disappeared. Also converting an answer to a comment is not really a great consolation, if you examine it. Anyways, as long as someone gave the right answer...

Comment: Undeleted, also, *you did not have to delete it just because someone else asked for it* - so we don't delete just because someone flagged to delete, we review and than take a decision.. hence we take time to handle flags.